# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException in input string

Tags: java, numberformatexception

```
public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int num = 6;
    int[] sticks = new int[num];
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        sticks[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    }
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(sticks[i]);
    }

  }}
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4 5 8 6 4 2"

Comment: enter each number on a new line...

Comment: Because `4 5 8 6 4 2` is not a valid number. Note the spaces.

Answer (score 4):

The string `"4 5 8 6 4 2"` cannot be parsed as a number. Try `split`ting it, or enter each number on a separate line.